# How do I create Ldarg_S instruction in Mono.Cecil?

Tags: c#, mono

In Mono.Cecil, when using `Ldarg_S` to create an instruction, the straightforward approach:

```
Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, 4);
```

doesn't work, since [Mono.Cecil expects](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/8b689ecdc890cbf3715ba8775de1d713d71f09f3/Mono.Cecil.Cil/Instruction.cs#L231) the operand type to be `OperandType.InlineI`, while the operand type of `OpCodes.Ldarg_S` is `ShortInlineArg`. Instead, I need to use the [`Create (OpCode opcode, ParameterDefinition parameter) : Instruction`](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/8b689ecdc890cbf3715ba8775de1d713d71f09f3/Mono.Cecil.Cil/Instruction.cs#L292) overload.

This requires to initialize the `ParameterDefinition` which, in turn, needs the following parameters:

- `string name`
- `ParameterAttributes attributes`
- `TypeReference parameterType`

What are those things? How do I specify that I just need the fourth (or fifth, or sixth) argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an in-depth inspection of Mono.Cecil's source code, it appears that there is no way to produce an instruction as simple as `ldarg.s 4`.

Instead, what Mono.Cecil does is that it needs you to specify the `ParameterDefinition` which is then matched with the list of parameters of a method in order to find the actual index.

The easiest way is to use `MethodDefinition.Parameters` property to retrieve the corresponding one by index and pass it to `Instruction.Create`. Possibly, the goal of this approach is to make it safer for the caller to manage the parameters by specifying a given parameter and let Mono.Cecil determine the actual index. It can, indeed, be a bit tricky for the caller to determine the actual index, especially in a case of instance methods where `ldarg.0` refers to `this`, and not the actual first parameter.